# relative path not working in java swing

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, ms-access, relative-path

So this swing program runs fine when given an absolute path for accessing database. But when I'm trying to access the database using a relative path, the program doesn't run. I've kept the MS Access database in the src folder itself in Eclipse. So how should I correct it ?

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.util.Vector;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


    public class r_search_1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

        JFrame frame1;
        JLabel l0, l1, l2;
        JComboBox c1;
        JButton b1;
        Connection con;
        ResultSet rs, rs1;
        Statement st, st1;
        PreparedStatement pst;
        String ids;
        static JTable table;
        String[] columnNames = {"SECTION NAME", "REPORT NAME", "CONTACT", "LINK"};
        String from;

          Vector v = new Vector();

        r_search_1() {

            l0 = new JLabel("Fetching Search Results...");
            l0.setForeground(Color.blue);
            l0.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
            l1 = new JLabel("Search");
            b1 = new JButton("submit");
            l0.setBounds(100, 50, 350, 40);
            l1.setBounds(75, 110, 75, 20);
            b1.setBounds(150, 150, 150, 20);
            b1.addActionListener(this);

            setTitle("Search Executive Reports :) ");
            setLayout(null);
            //setVisible(true);
            setSize(500, 500);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            add(l0);
            add(l1);;
            add(b1);
            try {

                File dbFile = new File("executive_db.accdb");
                String path = dbFile.getAbsolutePath();
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ= " + path);
                //String url="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ= " + path;

                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

                st = con.createStatement();
                rs = st.executeQuery("select index_name from Index1");

                while (rs.next()) {
                    ids = rs.getString(1);
                    v.add(ids);

                }
                c1 = new JComboBox(v);
                c1.setEditable(true);c1.setSelectedItem("");

                c1.setBounds(150, 110, 150, 20);

                add(c1);
                st.close();
                rs.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            setVisible(true);
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if (ae.getSource() == b1) {
                showTableData();
            }

        }

        public void showTableData() {

            frame1 = new JFrame("Database Search Result");
            frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //TableModel tm = new TableModel();
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
            model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);
    //DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(tm.getData1(), tm.getColumnNames());
    //table = new JTable(model);
            table = new JTable();
            table.setModel(model);
            table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
            table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
            JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
            scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
                    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
            scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
            from = (String) c1.getSelectedItem();

            String uname = "";
            String email = "";
            String pass = "";
            String cou = "";

            try {

                 pst = con.prepareStatement("select distinct Section.Section_Name,Report.Report_Name,Report.Link,Contact.Contact_Name "
                            + "FROM (( Section INNER JOIN Report ON Report.Section_ID=Section.Section_ID ) INNER JOIN Contact ON Contact.Contact_ID=Report.Contact_ID )  LEFT JOIN Metrics ON Metrics.Report_ID=Report.Report_ID  "
                            + " WHERE Section.Section_Name LIKE '%"+from+"%' OR Report.Report_Name LIKE '%"+from+"%' OR Metrics.Metric_Name LIKE '%"+from+"%' OR Contact.Contact_Name LIKE '%"+from+"%' ");
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                int i = 0;
                while (rs.next()) {
                    uname = rs.getString("Section_Name");
                    email = rs.getString("Report_Name");
                    pass = rs.getString("Contact_Name");
                    cou = rs.getString("Link");
                    model.addRow(new Object[]{uname, email, pass, cou});
                    i++;
                }
                if (i < 1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Record Found", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                if (i == 1) {
                    System.out.println(i + " Record Found");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(i + " Records Found");
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            frame1.add(scroll);
            frame1.setVisible(true);
            frame1.setSize(1000, 400);
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            new r_search_1();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Java projects, by default, run Java with the working directory as the root of the project. Therefore, the relative file `new File("executive_db.accdb")` is referring to a file directly within the project, whereas (by the sound of it) you've placed the file within the 'src' directory.

Your options are therefore either:

- Change the relative file definition to be `new File("src/executive_db.accdb")`
- Alter the working directory of Java by changing your Run Configuration. This can be performed by choosing Run -> Run Configurations, navigating to your run configuration, and changing the 'Working directory' value in the 'Arguments' tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the file in eclipse project folder rather than source folder you could directly access it like

```
File dbFile = new File("executive_db.accdb");
```

By default if you put a file in src folder eclipse will copy that to class folder while compiling and will be accessible. If this isn't the case you can copy the file to class folder and use `ClassLoader` to get the path.

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("executive_db.accdb");
File dbFile = new File(url.getPath());
```